# Java HttpClient check responseBody for error message

Tags: java, file, io, httpclient, response

I have a httpclient which gets a streamed xls file and writes it to a temp file. However, the response can return an error message with a 200 code.

Is there anyway of checking the responseBody streamed back before it's written to the file.

For example, if there is an error, it will return HTML with the word ERROR within it. So I would like to check for that, if it exists, exit the method and return a failure code to the front end.

The front end uses an AJAXRequest called from within an extjs grid.

```
 public void getReport(String login, String date, String type, String id){

        String url = "http://...";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        KerberizedNetegrityClient auth;       
        try {
            auth = new KerberizedNetegrityClient();
            cookie = auth.getCookieToken();
        } catch (NetegrityClientException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);

        method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));
        method.setRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);

        try{
            int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);

            if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                System.err.println("Method Failed: "+method.getStatusLine());
            }
            file = "file.xls";
            InputStream is = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
            int count = bis.read(bytes);
            while(count != -1 && count <= 8192){
                System.err.println("-");
                fos.write(bytes,0,count);
                count = bis.read(bytes);
            }
            if(count != -1){
                fos.write(bytes,0,count);                
            }
            fos.close();
            bis.close();
            method.releaseConnection();

            System.out.println("Done");



        }catch (HTTPException e){
            System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: "+ e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Fatal transport error: "+ e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            method.releaseConnection();
        }
        streamReport(file);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The response should have `content-type` header. Just check, if it's `text/html`, then it's an error, if it's `application/ms-excel` or `application/vnd.ms-excel` (not sure, check yours), then it's that you want. Also the excel response usually has `content-disposition`.

Comment: how do I then tell the ajax request that it's failed? Still unsure of that

Comment: Just examine response headers of failed request and of correct one with the `.xls`. At least `content-type` should be different.

Comment: no what I meant is, the response code is always 200, even if an error is returned. How do I change this in the httpclient so that the ajax request in the front end knows that an error has occurred?

Comment: 200 is a status code. I'm talking about response headers. See the `getResponseHeaders()` method.

Comment: if you look at my question I ask about "if it exists, exit the method and return a failure code to the front end"

Comment: I'm telling you to check response headers before reading a body. Check e.g. `content-type` header and return the failure if it is not `application/ms-excel`. An excel file could accidentally have word "ERROR" in it, you must check content type, because there is no other reliable way to detect it using body.